# Link to share app in the play store

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-play

On an app page in the play store there is a button which allows the user to share the app he/she is looking at, with fx facebook and google+. Is there a way i can create a shortcut from my app to this action. I know how to create an intent which opens a desired app page, but can you send the user directly to such an action.

Thanks Very much

Screenshot: (I'm talking about the blue highlighted button in the top)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some detail on why you want to do this?  As in, what is your ultimate goal?  Maybe you can get away with just replicating this functionality within your own app?

Comment: What i want is my users being able to share my app with the share button in the play store. So they click a button in my app and get taken to the play stores share function

Comment: But does it really have to be in the Play store?  For example, could you just create your own share intent that shares the app's market link directly?

Comment: I guess, i just thought this would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course create it.

This link from Android Developers Blog explains exactly what you want.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

UPDATE:

Sorry I misread your question. If you want to directly connect to the action in play store, it's not possible. You will not have control over it.

Comment: It sounds to me like Jakob is actually looking for a way to send an Intent that will open the user to the app's page in Google Play and then act as if the Share button were pressed from there.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, you want your app to be listed in that share action.

You have register this intent_filter for your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
       <activity
        android:name=".SendingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
          >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: No that's not what i meant, sorry. But thanks very much for your help. What i want is my users being able to share my app with the share button in the play store. So they click a button in my app and get taken to the play stores share function

Comment: i think you can't initiate the button press, you would only be able to bring your users here....